# I have two CSV files with 3 columns, I have to read this and compare this using hashmap()

Tags: java, csv, hashmap, compare

I have two csv files having 3 columns. I have to read this and compare this using `hashmap()` (multiple hashmaps).

Columns:

```
Name,Value, Address 
aaa,1,sdasdasd
bbb,2,sadasdasd
ccc,3,dsadasds
```

Code:

```
public class CompareFile {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        //HashMap<String, String> File1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String filepath1="D:\\XYZ\\File1.csv";
        String filepath2="D:\\XYZ\\File2.csv";
        HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> file1= new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> file2= new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();
        CompareFile compareFile = new CompareFile();
        file1=compareFile.readFileContents(filepath1);
        file2=compareFile.readFileContents(filepath2);
        //compareFile.CompareTwo(file1,file2);
    }//

    public HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> readFileContents(String file) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line=null;
        String[] str=null;
        HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> mapHashMap = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();
        while((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
        {
            str = line.split(",");
            HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            hashMap.put(str[1], str[2]);
            mapHashMap.put(str[0], hashMap);

        }
        for (Map.Entry<String, HashMap<String, String>> entry : mapHashMap.entrySet())
        {
           System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
        }return mapHashMap;
    }

    public void CompareTwo(HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> file1,HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> file2)throws IOException {
    {
        for(Map.Entry<String, HashMap<String, String>> entry1:file1.entrySet())
        {
            String key1=entry1.getKey();
            HashMap<String, String> value1=entry1.getValue();
            for(Map.Entry<String, HashMap<String, String>> entry2:file2.entrySet())
            {
                 String key2=entry2.getKey();
                 HashMap<String, String> value2=entry2.getValue();

                 if(key1==key2)
                 {

                     System.out.println(key2 + "\t" + value1 + "\t" + value2);
                 }


             }//

         }//
     }//
 }//
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Your question, as it stands now is just "write your code for me" which isn't really welcome. Try something and come back with specific problems you've encountered.

Comment: i have read the two csv's as in above format and i want to know the logic to compare these two files which i have put in hashmap

Comment: @UnfortuanteEngineerq Sorry, masking "write code for me" with "i want to know the logic" does not make it better.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should think about how to design your solution. Start by create some classes to represents what is a Csv file, what is each row in your csv file, and so on ...

For example create a java class named "CsvFile", which will contains some attributes that represent datas in your files, and these attributes could be some new java class to ("CsvRow" for example) ...

For reading your file, Use InputStreamReader java class to read and load your file.

```
File file = new File("C:/ ... ");
InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "ISO-8859-1");
```

Then you can loop over :

```
reader.read();
```

Like this :

```
String contentFile;
char[] buffer = new char[10000];
int n;
while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    contentFile.append(buffer, 0, n);
}
reader.close();
```

This is just how to read your file and get the content. But you still have to load this file content into your own classes.

Comment: CSV File is as shown in the question..3 columns thats all.. all i need to do is read it, load it and compare ..i have facing problem when i load it and i want the logic to compare